# POST field truncated by Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, post

I have a huge JSON string in JavaScript memory (~5MB). I need to post that to PHP, but Chrome keeps truncating my POST field.

At first, it was truncating it to 512KB. I changed the input maxlength to 100000000. Now Chrome truncates it to 856517 bytes.

I know it is Chrome because in the Network tab of the developer tools I see the Content-Length header and the truncated post field.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You could use AJAX instead of storing the value in an input element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by using a TEXTAREA instead of INPUT. Still not sure why there is a limit on the INPUT though.